# Chat problems when joining an existing meeting made using microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

We created an application with integration with microsoft graph and we are having some problems.

In the frontend application we are using the microsoft-teams sdk.

The meetings were created by microsoft graph api in version 1.0.

**WEB/BROWSER MICROSOFT TEAMS**: When the user enters the meeting via the web, I create a window.open and it works normally with the meeting chat appearing

**APP/DESKTOP MICROSOFT TEAMS**: When the user is using the microsoft teams application and tries to join a meeting, I use the deep link with the meeting link, but the chat does not appear

> example:
>   meetingTeams.meeting_join_web_url = https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19:meeting_MDNmOTA3NmUtZDhmMi00YzRmLTgyYjMtYzU4YzI2MDU5ZDQ4@thread.v2/
>   meetingTeams.meeting_join_url = https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19:meeting_MDNmOTA3NmUtZDhmMi00YzRmLTgyYjMtYzU4YzI2MDU5ZDQ4@thread.v2/

```
         microsoftTeams.initialize();
         microsoftTeams.getContext((context => {
            if (context.hostClientType === "web") {
                window.open(meetingTeams.meeting_join_web_url, "_blank")
                return;
            }

            const joinUrl = encodeURI(meetingTeams.meeting_join_url);
            microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(joinUrl); }));
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Could you please let us know if you have created this meeting using Graph API? Please share more context on the issue.

Comment: The meetings were created by microsoft graph api in version 1.0

Comment: There is a known issue with chat option for meetings created with Graph API. We are looking into it.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Thanks for the answer. Is there any forecast?

Comment: Not currently. We are looking into it.